# jQuery/PHP - Passing data from JS to PHP to perform deletion on database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to delete an object on my database through my own admin page. The way it works is simple: when I click the delete button in the row corresponding with the object, the JS code will grab the "id" attribute of the object and pass it to PHP to perform sql delete query. Although the console showed nothing, my code didn't work. Would you mind taking a glance at my code and find out what's wrong with it? I'm using PHP 7. All neccessary libraries is included. Thank you very much!

Here are my code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
            include("../connect.php");
            $sql = "select * from tbl";
            $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="data-id">
                <?php echo $data['id'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $data['name'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="delete.png" class="delete-button">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-button').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().siblings('.data-id').text();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/myproject/delete.php',
            data: {
                "id":id
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP delete.php

```
<?php
    include("../connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $sql = "delete from tbl where id=".$id;
        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    }
?>
```

PHP connect.php

```
<?php
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db");
    mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: warning :your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Thank you @FastSnail, but that problem is not important right now. I'll take care of it later :)

Comment: did you debug your code try to print sql query and see what is the problem  `$sql = "delete * from tbl where id=".$id;` ;echo $sql;` .for example may be id is not sending properly if block may not execute.and is there any errors.check browser console >network tab >click request you can see responce.

Comment: It shows an empty page. That's weird...

Comment: that mean if condition is not running cause `$_POST["id"]` is not there

Comment: change to this : var id = $(this).parent().parent().children('.data-id').text();

Comment: @MyName why should it be changed to that? I alerted the id and it worked well

Comment: @FastSnail Could it be something wrong with my ajax?

Comment: @FastSnail I remove the if clause and it notifies that "id" in the $_POST is unexpected

Comment: @BrotherEye first you should enable errors then you can see errors.and use browser network tab to see server response .dont remove if it's requred.one thing you can do is print all post values then you know if id is there. to print all post data use `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 2):

Your delete query syntax is wrong. It should be like below,

```
$sql = "delete from tbl where id=".$id;
```

Remove '*' from the query

**Update**: There are 2 more errors in your code & hopefully these corrections might fix your issue

Issue 1: Since your sending text inside a TD as id, it sends the id along the spaces in the HTML. So trim your value. Here is your query,

```
$sql = "delete from tbl where id=".trim($id);
```

Issue 2: This might be a typo error.  '$connnect' variable should be '$connect' in connect.php file.

Comment: I had remove the ' * ' before but it's still not working :(

Comment: @BrotherEye, I have updated my answer. Hopefully it helps you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  `$(this).parent().siblings('data-id').text();`

Should be  `$(this).parent().siblings('.data-id').text();`

Missing the dot (.) in the class name.

Comment: Ah...it's just typing mistake ^^! I do have that dot in my actual code :)

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code please `` for reserved mysql name

Change to below code :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```